# Apache htaccess rewrite using PHP script to change URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have urls that look like http://WEBSITE.com/?page_id=53?&nid=3104&lid=3100

As you can guess it is an ugly wordpress site, search function pulling up a result with id nid=3104 and lid=3100 .  Both numbers are necessary.

I would rather URLs look like http://WEBSITE.com/Chicago-Shelter-name
or http://WEBSITE.com/shelter/Chicago-Shelter-name

How can I get an .htaccess file to read the search result from a PHP script (that will pull if from SQL using the NID and LID numbers) and when the name comes back as "Chicago Shelter name" rewrite the url http://WEBSITE.com/Chicago-Shelter-name

Comment: No need to Apache rewrite `http://WEBSITE.com/?page_id=53?&nid=3104&lid=3100`, simply catch that in your *index.php* file and redirect the user with a "301 Moved Permanently" to the pretty URL'd page.

Comment: I believe the good looking URLs are not working yet, so 301 redirects are not an option, am I right?

Comment: My index.php file has nothing to do with this.  It is wordpress, so some other page called "?page_id=53" is running the search for nid=3104&lid=3100     I would like the URL to read human readable text as explained above.   How is a 301 redirect going to help when that changes to a different webpage.

Comment: I would like to display the contents of http://WEBSITE.com/?page_id=53?&nid=3104&lid=3100  while showing the fake URL http://WEBSITE.com/shelter/Chicago-Shelter-name    My understanding is that .htaccess Mod rewrite is required.  I confirmed it working on a blank page, but not my wordpress page_id=53

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Not easy.
.htaccess needs:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  
  RewriteRule    ^custom/name/?$  newfile.php?nid=3104&lid=3100    [NC,L]
  
</IfModule>
```

This being wordpress required a replica page of the entire search result.  The menu and sidebar will not reflect any updates, but I had to break out of wordpress.
Copied the source of the search result, removed the result, added the PHP that displays the result.
All inside of "newfile.php"

The above .htaccess file works.
If  http://WEBSITE.com/custom/name" is entered, it will display that entered URL
but in reality secretly display the result of "http://WEBSITE.com/newfile.php?nid=3104&lid=3100"

This is what I wanted.  Not the best, and now I must create lines of code for every single possible item in search.  But it works.